# How to preserve EGL context when pausing Android ndk app

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, egl

I am trying to improve openframeworks so that the GL context is preserved when pausing and resuming my game. So that I don't have to reload all textures after each pause. I don't expect you to know openframeworks code, I'll explain my problem independent of it.

I have java activity which loads a main_layout.xml file with a RelativeLayout inside another RelativeLayout. Then I instantiate a GLSurfaceView and add it to the inner RelativeLayout using `glContainer.addView(glView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));`. In onPause function, I call `glView.onPause();` on GLSurfaceView and in onResume, I call `glView.onResume();` on GLSurfaceView.

This code works but it destroys the gl surface in onPause (GLSurfaceView.surfaceDestroyed gets called on my GLSurfaceView, which is extended to OFGLSurfaceView, so that I can intercept this call).

To fix this, I added call to GLSurfaceView.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause with param 'true' to initialization of my GLSurfaceView. Now I see only black screen after pausing and resuming the game. I found out, that I can fix this by removing the GLSurfaceView from parent RelativeLayout and adding it back right away in onResume function: `glContainer.removeView( glView ); glContainer.addView( glView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) );`. This however destroys the gl surface again and forces me to reload textures.

There are no reinstantiations of either one of the RelativeLayouts or the GLSurfaceView (I checked it by looking at the code and then checking identities of those instances with System.identityHashCode).

main_layout.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/of_gl_surface_container" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <!-- add here other views' layouts -->
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Code in OFAndroidLifeCycle.java which handles events received from Activity:

```java
public static void glCreateSurface()
{
    if(mGLView == null)
    {
        mGLView = new OFGLSurfaceView(m_activity);

        OFGLSurfaceView glView = getGLView();

        glView.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause( true );

        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)glView.getParent();
        if( parent == null )
        {
            ViewGroup glContainer = getActivity().getSurfaceContainer();
            glContainer.addView(glView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        }
    }
}

public static void glPause()
{
    OFGLSurfaceView glView = getGLView();
    if( glView != null )
        glView.onPause();   
}

public static void glResume(ViewGroup glContainer)
{
    OFGLSurfaceView glView = getGLView();

    if( glView != null )
    {
        glView.onResume();

        glContainer.removeView( glView );
        glContainer.addView( glView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) );
    }
}
```

Well, I am just confused. Can someone elaborate a bit about how this should be done, what are some pitfalls or what approaches should I try?

Thanks.

Comment: In general this is bad practice. Phone users may have lots of suspended applications open, and it's not "nice" for applications to hold on to all of the memory when they are not actually running. The whole reason for this model is to free memory for the foreground process.

Comment: I am not forcing the phone to keep my resources in memory. Once Android runs out of memory, it can freely kill my app or just destroy the EGL context. I think its way worse practice to spend 4 seconds reloading all textures every time user pauses and then resumes the game to quickly check an incoming email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I later also created this question on gamedev.stackexchange.com and today I posted the solution there:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/171908/how-to-preserve-egl-context-when-pausing-android-ndk-app